# How happens-before covers single variable write and read?

Tags: java, cpu-cache, memory-model, java-memory-model

When dealing with happens before, I see it as about dealing with memory ordering and whether some memory ordering is valid with program order. For example, take the Dekker algorithm:

```java
public class DekkerMemoryReorderingExample {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void T1() {
        x = 1;
        int r1 = y;
    }

    public void T2() {
        y = 1;
        int r2 = x;
    }
}
```

In lack of synchronization we can observe result `(r1, r2) = (0, 0)`. No matter what happened under the hood - whether it's an instructions scheduling, CPU's instructions reordering, or write propagation delay (caching). It's all about StoreLoad *memory reordering*:

```
1. r1 = y
2. r2 = x
3. x = 1
4. y = 1
```

But when dealing with a single variable, how does happens before cover it in terms of memory ordering?
For example, imagine such a counter:

```java
public class UnsafeCounter {
    
    private int counter = 0;
    
    public synchronized int increment() {
        counter++;
    }

    public int get() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Clearly, this counter is broken because we read the counter variable not under the same lock, so we're not guaranteed to see writes preceding the read. More formally, there's no happens-before between write in `increment()` and read in `get()`.

But there's no relationship with other variables as it was in the Dekker example. So how can we speak about the visibility of writes in terms of the memory model, memory ordering, program order, and execution order? What kind of memory reordering can happen here (StoreLoad, StoreStore and etc..)? I specifically do not say anything about visibility on a lower level of hardware, because I want to understand how it works more abstractly and formally on the level of the memory model.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I'm reading the Java spec correctly, but it seems like in the presence of a data race (as in your program), a read is permitted to get any value written to the variable that is not directly inconsistent with happens-before.  Specifically, a read can't observe a write that happens-after it, and if a given write happens-before the read, it can't observe any other write that happens-earlier.

Comment: In your program, assuming `increment` and `get` are called by different threads, then none of the reads happen-before any of the writes or vice versa, so there'd be no restrictions.  If `increment` is called a total of N times, then any `get()` may return any value between 0 and N (but no values outside that range, and no tearing).  In particular, I think it is possible that if you call `get()` twice in sequence in the same thread, the first one can return a greater value than the second one.

Comment: The latter is interesting, because I tend to naively think of Java's memory model as similar to relaxed atomics in C/C++ (whose memory model I'm more familiar with), but relaxed atomics in C/C++ have coherence rules that wouldn't allow this.  On the other hand it's still stronger than C/C++ without atomics, in which case the data race causes completely undefined behavior, and you can read impossible values or summon nasal demons.

Comment: @NateEldredge in Java a read needs to see the most recent write before it in the memory order or it needs to see a concurrent write (so the read and write are not ordered by a happens-before edge). This is called happens-before consistent. With C++ you get undefined behavior when there is a data-race, in Java the behavior is still defined.

Comment: @pveentjer: Okay, I think that's equivalent to what I said (or at least to what I meant to say).  But in particular, for non-`volatile` objects it seems Java has nothing analogous to the C++ "modification order", which would require a total order on all writes to a given variable, even if they are concurrent.

Comment: @NateEldredge at this part my understanding becomes a bit fuzzy with respect to the JMM. So with opaque, you will get 'coherence', but it isn't the total order version of coherence like the C++ modification order gives; it is a partial order.  https://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html. So yes; at this level, the JMM and C++ modification order are AFAIK not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

> It's all about StoreLoad memory reordering

On the X86 you only need to deal with [StoreLoad] due to store buffers, but otherwise, all other reorderings are forbidden due to its strong memory model (TSO). But the compiler is still able to reorder loads/stores before they hit the CPU. So you still need compiler fences.

Apart from that, other platforms like ARM, have a weaker memory model that will allow for loads and stores to different addresses to be reordered. So it isn't all about StoreLoad memory reordering.

> So how can we speak about the visibility of writes in terms of the memory model

Visibility is very much concern at this level. It effectively means that the compiler should not optimize out the load or the store.

Imagine the getting code would look like this (I already inlined the 'get' method.

```
for(;;){
   if(unsafeCounter.counter==1){
     break;
   }
}
```

Since the read counter isn't special, the compiler could hoist reading the counter out of the loop like this:

```
if(unsafeCounter.counter!=1){
   for(;;){}
}
```

So even if a new value gets written, the reading thread will not see the new value once it enters the loop. So visibility is still very much a concern.

Another concern is atomicity. In this case, the counter is 32 bits, so the read/write is guaranteed to be atomic on 32/64 bit platform. But if you would have a long and run on a 32 bits platform, you could end up with a torn read (so the first 32 bits of 1 write and the last 32 bits from another write).

Last and not least is the coherence concern. So reordering of loads/stores to a single address. Coherence isn't provided by a plain load/store as can be seen with the following [example](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/basic/BasicJMM_05_Coherence.java) from JCStress.

```
 @JCStressTest
    @Outcome(id = "0, 0", expect = ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Doing both reads early.")
    @Outcome(id = "1, 1", expect = ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Doing both reads late.")
    @Outcome(id = "0, 1", expect = ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Doing first read early, not surprising.")
    @Outcome(id = "1, 0", expect = ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING, desc = "First read seen racy value early, and the second one did not.")
    @State
    public static class SameRead {

        private final Holder h1 = new Holder();
        private final Holder h2 = h1;

        private static class Holder {
            int a;
            int trap;
        }

        @Actor
        public void actor1() {
            h1.a = 1;
        }

        @Actor
        public void actor2(II_Result r) {
            Holder h1 = this.h1;
            Holder h2 = this.h2;

            // Spam null-pointer check folding: try to step on NPEs early.
            // Doing this early frees compiler from moving h1.a and h2.a loads
            // around, because it would not have to maintain exception order anymore.
            h1.trap = 0;
            h2.trap = 0;

            // Spam alias analysis: the code effectively reads the same field twice,
            // but compiler does not know (h1 == h2) (i.e. does not check it, as
            // this is not a profitable opt for real code), so it issues two independent
            // loads.
            r.r1 = h1.a;
            r.r2 = h2.a;
        }
    }
```

In the above example it can happen that the data value invariant is violated; so first you read a new value and then you go back and read an old value and therefore the code is incoherent.

Java Opaque access mode solves this [problem](https://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html).